# Regex evaluating three letter construction

Tags: regex

I'm trying to build a regex that would tell me if 3-letter string (being document series) is valid. Basically everything from "aaa" to "ard" should be valid and everything starting from "are" needs to be deemed invalid.
I got stuck with the condition as I can't really figure out how to build it. I've tried the one below, but it returns all "ar*" as valid, even though all "as*" and higher are considered invalid.

```
[a]{1}[a-r]{1}?[a-z](?(1)<=([s-z])([\Z])){1}
```

Would you please help me putting the correct code in place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^a(?:[a-q][a-z]|r[a-d])$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EKHcee/2/)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `a` - a `a` letter
- `(?:[a-q][a-z]|r[a-d])` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `[a-q][a-z]` - a letter from `a` to `q` followed with any ASCII lowercase letter
  - `|` - or
  - `r[a-d]` - `r` followed with a letter from `a` to `d`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Wow, just that simple? Many thanks for this!!!
A question though - what's wrong with using equation char?

Comment: @mikolajek There is no equation in your pattern, the `(?(1)...|...` is a [conditional construct](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html). It does not do what you expect. It checks if Group 1 was matched, but your Group 1 is `([s-z])`, after the group match check. Besides, you seem to use an anchor inside a character class. `[\Z]` matches just `Z` (or ``\`` or `Z` depending on the regex engine).